# Android apk deploy fails (INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE)

Tags: android, apk, adb

I'm trying to deploy an app to my android device through Android Studio and I get the following error:

> Package signatures do not match the previously installed version

So I thought there was another version of the same app on the device and I tried to uninstall it but the app does not appear in the installed apps list. Apparently there is no other version of the app installed on the devices.
I also tried to install it through adb:

```
adb install [APK_FILE]
```

and I got the following error:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

Tried also to uninstall it through adb:

```
adb uninstall [APP_PACKAGE_NAME]
```

and I got this error:

> Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Lastly I tried to install the version of the app which is published on the playstore and it doesn't allow me to install it, closing the installation with a generic error. I checked the logcat logs and I have found this:

> 07-17 20:38:38.219  6956  6956 E Finsky  : [1] tho.onReceive(17): Error -505 while installing [APP_PACKAGE]: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package [APP_PACKAGE] signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

I found many occurrences of this problem on the internet and the solutions are mostly "uninstall the previous version of the app", but I cannot do it because the app is not listed among the installed apps of the device.

Comment: I used to get this problem before. In my case there is another version of app installed in guest mode under settings/multiple users. Change your phone to guest mode and try to find if any version of your app installed and then remove it and change back to admin mode.

Comment: I have an Honor 6 with Android Marshmallow, it doesn't seem to have a guest mode or the possibility to have multiple users.